# testDeviceId's are not working in google-mobile-ads flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

I was trying to set my test device id with the requestConfiguration. For checking whether setup for testdevice is successful, I filtered `logcat` in android studio with `setTestDeviceIds` but it's showing me the following log

```
2021-03-31 04:17:36.907 27185-27185/? I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")) to get test ads on this device.
```

So setting up for test device are not working and I can't test with real ads. As I'm passing testDeviceId's this log was supposed to not appear. You can see I'm passing `testDeviceId`'s for both in `RequestConfiguration` and `bannerAd`.

#### Steps to reproduce

Here is my `main.dart` file

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:us/global/theme/app_themes.dart';
import 'package:us/utils/ad_helper.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  MobileAds.instance.initialize().then((InitializationStatus status) {
    print('Initialization done: ${status.adapterStatuses}');
    MobileAds.instance
        .updateRequestConfiguration(RequestConfiguration(
        testDeviceIds: AdHelper.allTestDevices));
  });


  runApp(
      MyApp()
  );
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      create: (_) => ThemeChanger(),
      child: new MaterialAppWithTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Const',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: theme.getDarkTheme ? ThemeData.dark():ThemeData.light(),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  static final AdRequest request = AdRequest(
    testDevices: AdHelper.allTestDevices,
  );

  BannerAd _bannerAdd;
  bool _isBannerAdLoaded = false;

  Future<InitializationStatus> _initGoogleMobileAds() {
    // TODO: Initialize Google Mobile Ads SDK
    return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    _bannerAdd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.homePageBannerAd,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      request: request,
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (_) {  // Future<SharedPrefData> _setDarkMode(bool darkMode) async{
          //   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          //   log.i('Current dark mode  $darkMode.');
          //   await prefs.setBool('darkmode', darkMode);
          //   log.i('Dark mode toggled successfully');
          //   return await getPersistedData();
          // }
          setState(() {
            _isBannerAdLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
          // Releases an ad resource when it fails to load
          ad.dispose();

          print('Ad load failed (code=${error.code} message=${error.message})');
        },
      ),
    );

    _bannerAdd.load();

  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //this gonna give us total height and with of our device
    return Scaffold(
      // bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  this._isBannerAdLoaded? Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35),
                    height: 72.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAdd),
                  ):Text('')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my `adhelper.dart` file

```dart
import 'dart:io';

class AdHelper{

  static String TEST_BANNER_AD = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

 static String get homePageBannerAd{
   if(Platform.isAndroid){
     return TEST_BANNER_AD;
   }
   else if(Platform.isIOS){
     return TEST_BANNER_AD;
   }
   else
     throw new UnsupportedError("Platform is not supported..");
 }

 static List<String> get allTestDevices{

       String MY_REDMI_NOTE_9="xxxxxxxxxxx";


   return [MY_REDMI_NOTE_9];
  }

}
```

#### Flutter doctor

Run `flutter doctor` and paste the output below:

Click To Expand

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

#### Flutter dependencies

Run `flutter pub deps -- --style=compact` and paste the output below:

Click To Expand

```
Dart SDK 2.12.0
Flutter SDK 2.0.1
us_constitution 1.0.0+1

dependencies:
- dynamic_text_highlighting 2.2.0 [flutter]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection meta typed_data vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_svg 0.19.3 [flutter meta path_drawing vector_math xml]
- flutter_xlider 3.4.0 [flutter]
- google_mobile_ads 0.11.0+4 [meta flutter]
- logger 1.0.0
- path_provider 2.0.1 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_macos path_provider_linux path_provider_windows]
- provider 5.0.0 [collection flutter nested]
- shared_preferences 2.0.5 [meta flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface shared_preferences_linux shared_preferences_macos shared_preferences_web shared_preferences_windows]
- sqflite 1.3.2+4 [flutter sqflite_common path]
- url_launcher 6.0.3 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_windows url_launcher_web]

dev dependencies:
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters charcode collection matcher meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph typed_data]

transitive dependencies:
- async 2.5.0 [collection]
- boolean_selector 2.1.0 [source_span string_scanner]
- characters 1.1.0
- charcode 1.2.0
- clock 1.1.0
- collection 1.15.0
- convert 2.1.1 [charcode typed_data]
- fake_async 1.2.0 [clock collection]
- ffi 1.0.0
- file 6.1.0 [meta path]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter js characters collection meta typed_data vector_math]
- js 0.6.3
- matcher 0.12.10 [stack_trace]
- meta 1.3.0
- nested 1.0.0 [flutter]
- path 1.8.0
- path_drawing 0.4.1+1 [vector_math meta path_parsing flutter]
- path_parsing 0.1.4 [vector_math meta]
- path_provider_linux 2.0.0 [path xdg_directories path_provider_platform_interface flutter]
- path_provider_macos 2.0.0 [flutter]
- path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.0 [flutter meta platform plugin_platform_interface]
- path_provider_windows 2.0.0 [path_provider_platform_interface meta path flutter ffi win32]
- petitparser 3.1.0 [meta]
- platform 3.0.0
- plugin_platform_interface 1.0.3 [meta]
- process 4.1.0 [file path platform]
- shared_preferences_linux 2.0.0 [flutter file meta path path_provider_linux shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_macos 2.0.0 [shared_preferences_platform_interface flutter]
- shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.0.0 [flutter]
- shared_preferences_web 2.0.0 [shared_preferences_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins meta]
- shared_preferences_windows 2.0.0 [shared_preferences_platform_interface flutter file meta path path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- source_span 1.8.0 [charcode collection path term_glyph]
- sqflite_common 1.0.3+1 [synchronized path meta]
- stack_trace 1.10.0 [path]
- stream_channel 2.1.0 [async]
- string_scanner 1.1.0 [charcode source_span]
- synchronized 2.2.0+2
- term_glyph 1.2.0
- test_api 0.2.19 [async boolean_selector collection meta path source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph matcher]
- typed_data 1.3.0 [collection]
- url_launcher_linux 2.0.0 [flutter]
- url_launcher_macos 2.0.0 [flutter]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 2.0.1 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 2.0.0 [url_launcher_platform_interface meta flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- url_launcher_windows 2.0.0 [flutter]
- vector_math 2.1.0
- win32 2.0.0 [ffi]
- xdg_directories 0.2.0 [meta path process]
- xml 4.5.1 [collection convert meta petitparser]
```

---

Answer (score 8):

In my case this works

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize().then((InitializationStatus status) {
    print('Initialization done: ${status.adapterStatuses}');
    MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
      RequestConfiguration(
          tagForChildDirectedTreatment:
              TagForChildDirectedTreatment.unspecified,
          testDeviceIds: <String>["list of test device ids seprated by ,(comas)"]),
    );
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can do it like this

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  // thing to add
  RequestConfiguration configuration = RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: ['E46609DD331AF2754D38B3DCE3ED011B']);
  MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```