# Can not find test device ID in logcat for Ad Mob in Flutter. Where to find it?

Tags: android, flutter, admob, test-ads

Can not find `test device ID` in logcat for Ad Mob in Flutter. Where to find it? I am scanning through `Logcat` in Android Studio, but it is just not there.

Currently using this in `main.dart`:

```
  MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
      RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: ['MY MISSING TEST ID']));
```

And this is also not sending anything in the console nor Logcat to actually give me the Test ID that I require to use the sample / test ads from Google AdMob in my Flutter Android Simulator in Android Studio.

Can someone help me understand what I need to do? Note that the app is not published yet and I am using simulators only.

I checked here:
[testDeviceId's are not working in google-mobile-ads flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881383/testdeviceids-are-not-working-in-google-mobile-ads-flutter) and [How can I get device ID for Admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524752/how-can-i-get-device-id-for-admob)

But no luck, sadly. I do see this in the console log, don't know if they are related:

```
I/Ads     (29143): This request is sent from a test device.
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(29143): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(29143): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
```

PS: also tried this, without any luck:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  // thing to add
  RequestConfiguration configuration = RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: ['TEST_EMULATOR']);
  MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

Here is my full home.dart code:

```
 late BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _isAdLoaded = false;

 @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _loadBannerAd() {
    debugPrint('Attempting to load Banner Ad...');
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111', // Replace with your ad unit ID
      size: AdSize.banner,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          debugPrint('Banner Ad loaded: $ad');
          setState(() {
            _isAdLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
          debugPrint('Banner Ad failed to load: $ad, $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );

    _bannerAd.load();
  }

  Widget _buildBannerAd() {
    debugPrint('Is Ad Loaded? $_isAdLoaded');
    return _isAdLoaded
        ? AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd)
        : SizedBox(height: 50); // Placeholder if ad is not loaded
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadBannerAd();
    }
```

Main.dart:
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
/// run app etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/test-ads#android), you need to do the following steps:

1. Use a test ad with an id (I.E. 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111' for Android)
2. Make a request to load an ad
3. Check the logs for a message like this:

> I/Ads: Use   RequestConfiguration.Builder
> .setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231"))
> to get test ads on this device.

4. You will probably have a different device id there, but take that device id and set it using:

   ```
   MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
   RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: ['33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231']));
   ```

**Did you follow all of these steps? Maybe you did not make an ad request?**

Also, pay attention that iOS simulators and Android emulated devices are automatically configured as test devices, but you have to add physical devices manually (you didn't mention which type of device you are testing on).

Comment: I did follow that, yes. The problem is that I do not see I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder .setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231")) in the console nor Logcat. So it is an Android emulator (also tried on iOS btw) which is indeed a test device, but sadly no ads are loaded.  When you say to request to load an ad, isn't this enough?

      request: AdRequest(),

Comment: @Johan - Please edit your question and add the code you have for loading an ad.

Comment: @Johan - Do you see any errors in the callbacks you registered to? Or any other logs?